# How to create a circular button in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

I want to make a circular thumbs up and thumbs down button.

Should I use a ImageView or a Button as the super class?

How would I do this in Swift?

Answer (score 169, accepted):

Here is an example round button:

**Swift 3, 4, 5:**

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    let button = UIButton(type: .custom)
    button.frame = CGRect(x: 160, y: 100, width: 50, height: 50)
    button.layer.cornerRadius = 0.5 * button.bounds.size.width
    button.clipsToBounds = true
    button.setImage(UIImage(named:"thumbsUp.png"), for: .normal)
    button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(thumbsUpButtonPressed), for: .touchUpInside)
    view.addSubview(button)
}

@objc func thumbsUpButtonPressed() {
    print("thumbs up button pressed")
}
```

**Swift 2.x:**

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    let button = UIButton(type: .Custom)
    button.frame = CGRect(x: 160, y: 100, width: 50, height: 50)
    button.layer.cornerRadius = 0.5 * button.bounds.size.width
    button.clipsToBounds = true
    button.setImage(UIImage(named:"thumbsUp.png"), forState: .Normal)
    button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(thumbsUpButtonPressed), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
    view.addSubview(button)
}

func thumbsUpButtonPressed() {
    print("thumbs up button pressed")
}
```

Comment: To get this to work I had to add `button.clipsToBounds = true`

Comment: Is there any way to do this with constraints? I'm not using the `button.frame = CGRect...` code.

Comment: @ArchieGertsman, sure.  Set an aspect ratio constraint (width == height) so that your button is square.  Then move the code `button.layer.cornerRadius = ...` to an override of `viewDidLayoutSubviews`.  You have to do it there because you need to make sure *Auto Layout* has run.

Comment: Thank you! Works perfectly..

Comment: Hi is there a version which works in swift 5?

Comment: This answer's version still works in Swift 5, @ch271828n. Maybe you are missing the `button.layer.borderWidth = ...`  :)

Comment: @ArchieGertsman use like this : button.pinToSuperview(leading: nil, trailing: 20, top: nil, bottom: 25, width: 70, height: 50)