# Making Buttons Circular in swift4

Tags: xcode, uibutton, uistoryboard, swift4, ios11

I have few buttons which are added from Storyboard(not by code) . I want to make it circular in shape . How do I do it? I don't want a circular button added from code but from storyboard.Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create a circular button in Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26050655/how-to-create-a-circular-button-in-swift)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can make use of `IBDesginable` to make `UIButton` circular even in storyboard.

Add this class `RoundButton` in your project.

```
@IBDesignable class RoundButton : UIButton{

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        sharedInit()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        sharedInit()
    }

    override func prepareForInterfaceBuilder() {
        sharedInit()
    }

    func sharedInit() {
        refreshCorners(value: cornerRadius)
    }

    func refreshCorners(value: CGFloat) {
        layer.cornerRadius = value
    }

    @IBInspectable var cornerRadius: CGFloat = 15 {
        didSet {
            refreshCorners(value: cornerRadius)
        }
    }
}
```

Follow below steps to make it designable in Storyboard.

1. Add `UIButton` in viewcontroller and set some background color.

[image]

2. Set Width and Height same. Here both are 100.

[image]

3. Now you can see one more property named `Corner Radius` we declared in `RoundButton` class. Set it to 50 as half of Width/Height. You can set according to your need.

[image]

Now you can see rounded corner button within storyboard. You do not need to run code to see changes. You can make reuse of class in any other project to make button circular.

More about [IBDesignable](http://blog.supereasyapps.com/how-to-create-round-buttons-using-ibdesignable-on-ios-11/).

Comment: This will correctly create a circular button, but note that the target area will remain unchanged - i.e. it will still be square and therefore tappable outside the actual button.

Answer (score 4):

Very simple and easy.

```
yourButton.layer.cornerRadius = yourButton.frame.width/2
```

this will surely going to work.
Eat sleep code repeat

Answer (score 0):

```
let button = UIButton(type: .custom)
    button.frame = CGRect(x: 160, y: 100, width: 50, height: 50)
    button.layer.cornerRadius = 0.5 * button.bounds.size.width
    button.clipsToBounds = true
    button.setImage(UIImage(named:"thumbsUp.png"), for: .normal)
    button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(thumbsUpButtonPressed), for: .touchUpInside)
```

Comment: The OP literally said he didn't want to add it by code.